# Get max date of variable in loop comparing with maturity date

Tags: sql-server, variables, max, database-cursor

I am building a report in SQL Server which will return all the coupon payments for each of my bonds per coupon date. I have in a table information about each bond (maturity, coupon, coupon frequency etc) and I am building the coupon payment calendar for each one.I am stuck in the point where the last coupon payment is not equal to the maturity. In that case I would like to add one more line on this bond's calendar with maturity date payment.

Here is my code so far:

```
----Declare variables for loop-----
DECLARE @innertable TABLE
(
     isin        VARCHAR(12), 
     alt_id      VARCHAR(11), 
     coupon_date DATE,
     maturity    DATE
);

DECLARE @id INT;
DECLARE @bcursor AS CURSOR;
DECLARE @NextDate DATE;
DECLARE @MatDate DATE;
DECLARE @isin VARCHAR(12);
DECLARE @alt_id VARCHAR(11);

---------SET you primary cursor, in this case ID--------------
SET @bcursor = CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT id
    FROM Bond_info;

OPEN @bcursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM @bcursor INTO @id;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    ------------SET the inner loop------------------ 
    --PRINT CAST(@id AS INT);

    SET @isin =
        (
            SELECT isin
            FROM Bond_info
            WHERE id = @id
        );
    SET @alt_id =
        (
            SELECT alt_id
            FROM Bond_info
            WHERE id = @id
        );
    SET @NextDate =
        (
            SELECT first_coupon_date
            FROM Bond_info
            WHERE id = @id
        );
    SET @MatDate =
        (
            SELECT maturity
            FROM Bond_info
            WHERE id = @id
        );

    WHILE @NextDate <= @MatDate
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @innertable (coupon_date, isin, alt_id, maturity)
        VALUES (@NextDate, @isin, @alt_id, @MatDate);

        SET @NextDate =
                (
                    SELECT DATEADD(month, (12 / t1.coupon_freq), @NextDate)
                    FROM bond_info t1
                    WHERE id = @id
                );
    END;

    ---------- END of inner loop ------------
END;

FETCH NEXT FROM @bcursor INTO @id;

CLOSE @bcursor;
DEALLOCATE @bcursor;

--------------SHOW RESULT TABLE-----------
SELECT *
FROM @innertable;


----------integrate data and Calculate cash flow-----------
SELECT 
    t1.isin, 
    t1.alt_id,
    t1.coupon_date,
    t1.maturity,
    Bond_info.coupon, 
    Bond_info.coupon_type, 
    Bond_info.coupon_freq,
    t2.account_number,
    (t2.quantity * Bond_info.coupon) as coupon_payment_annual,
    (t2.quantity * Bond_info.coupon) / Bond_info.coupon_freq as coupon_payment_freq,
    ((t2.quantity * Bond_info.coupon) / Bond_info.coupon_freq)*Bond_info.principal_factor as coupon_pmt_freq_factor,
    iif(t1.coupon_date = Bond_info.maturity,  (((t2.quantity * Bond_info.coupon) / Bond_info.coupon_freq)*Bond_info.principal_factor)+ t2.quantity,((t2.quantity * Bond_info.coupon) / Bond_info.coupon_freq)*Bond_info.principal_factor) as cash_flows
FROM 
    @innertable t1
INNER JOIN 
    Bond_info ON t1.isin = Bond_info.isin
INNER JOIN 
    portfolio_details t2 ON t1.isin = t2.id 
WHERE 
    t2.account_number IN ('Acc1', 'Acc2', 'Acc3', 'Acc4') 
ORDER BY 
    t2.account_number, t1.isin,t1.coupon_date
```

The table I get from this query looks like this:

[image: Result table screenshot]

For the second isin the last coupon_date <> Maturity_date so I would like to add the maturity date in the coupon_date .
Could someone help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: SQL is a set-based language. You don't need cursors or loops to calculate anything, except for very, very, very rare cases. Coupon calculations aren't one of them

Comment: For example, the inner loop can be replaced with a single `INSERT INTO SOmeTable SELECT isin, alt_id,...FROM bond_info`. It does nothing more than retrieve a single row's fields and write all of them as a single record to another table

Comment: That other table isn't needed either, the `SELECT` statement as-is can be used as a subquery or CTE in the other queries

Comment: **Consumable** sample data and expected results will help us help you.  Like @PanagiotisKanavos I very much doubt you actually need to `WHILE`/`CURSOR` here. The only times I use them is when looping for `sp_send_dbmail` and rare cases when a "set-based loop" is quicker (which combines the ideas of a set based solutions and `WHILE`/`CURSOR`).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for the comments! I am new to this and maybe is a stupid question but in order to better understand, how I will just insert into the table the data if I haven't generate them. For example, in my Bond_info table I have one line with the name of the bond the coupon, the frequency but not all the payment dates. This is what I try to calculate. The payment dates based on the maturity date I have and the coupon frequency. I couldn't figure out any other way  except loop where I can do that.